# Insufficient IAM privileges. Unable to determine if instance profile 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role' exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, command-line-interface

every time i try to create an environment from my cli it pop up this error
 `ERROR   Unable to assign role. Please verify that you have permission to pass this role: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role.`
and give me failed to launch environment
even though i setup the aws access key and secret access key and give the user the permissions of administrator

Comment: Seems you are using different user (not admin) or account then you think.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a strictly defined [policy evaluation logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow).

> 1. Deny evaluation – By default, all requests are denied. This is called an implicit deny. The AWS enforcement code evaluates all policies within the account that apply to the request. These include AWS Organizations SCPs, resource-based policies, identity-based policies, IAM permissions boundaries, and session policies. In all those policies, the enforcement code looks for a Deny statement that applies to the request. This is called an explicit deny. If the code finds even one explicit deny that applies, the code returns a final decision of Deny. If there is no explicit deny, the code continues.

As you can see, the first step checks for an explicit deny in all policies within the account that apply to the request. Although you have the admin permissions there could be  Organizations SCPs, resource-based policies, IAM permissions boundaries, or another IAM policy attached to your IAM account or group that explicitly deny passing a role. If you have access just check them one by one. Or ask your administrator to do that.